# D3 V4 dynamic data update not working

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to dynamically add a path to already existing list of paths. Below is the code snippet

```
        const pathArcs = arcGroup.selectAll('.arc')
          .data(links).enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('class', 'arc')
          .style('fill', 'none')
          .on('click', d => { //some logic here
               links.push(new Data());
          }

        // update
        pathArcs.attr('d', path)
          .style('stroke', '#0000ff')
          .style('stroke-width', '2px')
          .transition().duration(1500)
          .attrTween('stroke-dasharray', tweenDash);

        // exit
        pathArcs.exit().remove();
```

As shown above when I click on the line, I try to draw a new line with different angle by just pushing the new line data to list. However I don't see the line being drawn. The same code used to work in V3 version. I read about change in V4 where data life cycle has been changed and suggested to use merge, Hence I tried to use merge but still new line is not getting drawn. However if I nest the code of creation of line it works as shown below.

```
   const pathArcs = arcGroup.selectAll('.arc')
      .data(links).enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('class', 'arc')
      .style('fill', 'none')
      .on('click', d => { //some logic here
           links.push(new Data());
           const pathArcs1 = arcGroup.selectAll('.arc')
             .data(links).enter()
             .append('path')
             .attr('class', 'arc')
             .style('fill', 'none')
             .attr('d', path)
             .style('stroke', '#0000ff')
             .style('stroke-width', '2px')
             .transition().duration(1500)
             .attrTween('stroke-dasharray', tweenDash)
      }

    // update
    pathArcs.attr('d', path)
      .style('stroke', '#0000ff')
      .style('stroke-width', '2px')
      .transition().duration(1500)
      .attrTween('stroke-dasharray', tweenDash);

    // exit
    pathArcs.exit().remove();
```

Though the above code works but it has other issues like transformation/translation doesn't work properly for new lines.

Not sure why merge is not working, [here](https://github.com/kprasad99/angular-d3/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts) is the complete ts file.

### Update

```
   function drawLine(){

        const pathArcs = arcGroup.selectAll('.arc')
          .data(links);

        pathArcs.attr("class", "arc");

        pathArcs.enter()
          .append('path').attr('class', 'arc')
          .style('fill', 'none')
          .on('click', function(d){
                links.push({
                    type: 'LineString',
                    coordinates: [
                        [data[0].lon, data[0].lat],
                        [data[4].lon, data[4].lat]
                    ]
                });
                drawLine();
          }).merge(pathArcs).attr('d', path)
          .style('stroke', '#0000ff')
          .style('stroke-width', '2px')
          .transition().duration(1500)
          .attrTween('stroke-dasharray', tweenDash);

        // exit
        pathArcs.exit().remove();

        };
        drawLine();
```

Now though merge is working now, however I see transition (drawing line from `a -> b`) is getting triggered for all lines. How can I make only new line to be redrawn? I believe my merge is still not working as expected.

Comment: The block of code beneath your `//update` comment is actually the enter selection.

Comment: I tried pathArcs.attr('d', path) with arcGroup.selectAll('.arc').attr('d', path) still no luck.  how to update the above snippet for update selection.